# Auxiliary trigonometric identities [Identidades Trigonométricas Auxiliares]

Tags: trigonometry

I need to show two auxiliary trigonometric identities:

1) $\sec^2x = \tan ^2x + 1 (\cos x \neq 0)$

2) $\csc^2x = \cot^2x +1 (\sin x \neq 0)$

How could I do it?

---

[Original Portuguese]

Identidades Trigonométricas Auxiliares
Sendo preciso mostrar a demonstração das duas fórmulas das IDENTIDADES TRIGONOMÉTRICAS AUXILIARES:

1) sec²x = tg²x + 1 (cos x ≠ 0)

2) cossec²x = cotg²x = 1 (sen x ≠ 0)

Como seria possível fazê-lo???

Comment: Welcome! It will be nice if you write in English .

Comment: @Iuli [Consensus on meta in the past](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la) has been very strongly in favor of people posting questions in their native languages. The idea that it is much better to get a coherent, well-expressed question in Portuguese, and which can be translated, than to get an unintelligible question in English.

Comment: @ MJD: I translated the question to English already, it's just that the OP has not yet accepted the edit.

Comment: @RodCarvalho Are you sure? I would expect that your edit would go into the queue to be approved by high-reputation users, not by OP. But it is not in the queue.

Comment: @ MJD: It said it was sent to the queue after I submitted the edit. In any case, Peter translated it in the meantime.

Comment: I think in such cases it might be a good idea to leave the original language in the post, to facilitate correction of translation errors.

Comment: OH!! Sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm brazilian and I cannot express my question very well in English; But I'm so gratify for the answers. Really thanks, you were my salvation. Haha...

Comment: @Ana It is OK to post in Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, you get, dividing by $\cos^2 x$ (if this is $\ne 0$)
\[ \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2 x} + \frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x} = \frac 1{\cos^2 x} \]
which gives
\[  \tan^2 x + 1 = \mathrm{sec}^2 x \]
Dividing the first identity by $\sin^2 x$ we get
\[ \frac{\sin^2x}{\sin^2 x} + \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} = \frac 1{\sin^2 x} \]
which gives
\[  1 + \cot^2 x = \mathrm{csc}^2 x \]

Comment: Oh my God, thanks!!! Really really really really thank you!! I was not finding it in any brazilian website, you've helped a lot. FOREVER GRATIFIED!!! I'm so happy for this. Sorry for bother you...Haha